# HMMT 2014 Geometry anglechasing

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle
with circumcenter $O$ such that $AB = 4, AC = 5, BC = 6$. Let $D$ be the foot of the altitude
from $A$ to $BC$ and $E$ be the intersection of lines $AO$ and $BC$. Suppose that $X$ is on $BC$
between $D$ and $E$ such that there is a point $Y$ on $AD$ satisfying $XY \parallel AO$ and $Y O \perp AX$.
Determine the length of $BX$.

[image]

I have read the solution but I cant seem to see that angles $TDX$ and $XAL$ are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because quadrilateral $ALDT$ is cyclic as $\angle ADL=\angle ATL =90^{\circ}$.